# paging with nhibernate and mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, pagination

I've found very interesting tutorial for pagination using nhibernate
http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Simple-paging-with-ASPNET-MVC-and-NHibernate.aspx

How can these  `public PagedList<PSScript> GetPaged(int pageIndex, int pageSize)` query be rewriten for use without futures (main reason for these is that I should have working version for other databases, like firbird, etc.)

Or if you have some other interesting pagination tutorials to share, please do.

Thanks

Comment: What are you binding your data to in your view? If you are binding to a table or grid, I've found [JQGrid's](http://www.trirand.net/demo.aspx) auto-magicalical paging works just fine with NHibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create the queries without `Futures`. The only difference is that you will have two roundtrips to the database instead of one. I don't think that this will be a problem in your scenario.

Something like this should work:

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    var rowCount = session.CreateCriteria<PSScript>()
                        .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
                        .UniqueResult<Int32>();

    var results = session.CreateCriteria<PSScript>()
        .SetFirstResult((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
        .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
        .ToList<PSScript>();

    return new PagedList<PSScript>(results, pageSize, pageSize, rowCount);
}
```

Comment: if I'm not asking too much, can you show me on concrete example.